# Script to flag spam or inappropriate content for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any easy-to-install script out there for Rails app?

A flag button just like youtube, for user to click when spam or profanity or inappropriate graphic is found in a community post. That flag will notify the admin to review the complained entry so to take necessary action, such as removing the inappropriate content.

Comment: For what? You need more context.

Comment: Sorry, just added more context to my question.

Comment: I think a good example is right here on this post there is a flag button, that's what you want right ? I think you should specify what language you are working in though. it may also benefit you to accept some more answers to questions you have asked in the past

Comment: Thanks. It's for Rails. I just want something dead simple.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite old, but it still works as Akismet keeps his detection up to date: http://railscasts.com/episodes/65-stopping-spam-with-akismet